# How to install get-pip.py to python

Tags: python

Im trying to install pip but i cant ı dont know what to do with `get-pip.py` even after ı read it ı tried copying it to cmd and it closed ı tried the same thing on python but it said `Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module> NameError: name 'main' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

pip uses PyPI as the default source for packages and their dependencies. So whenever you type:

```
pip install package_name
```

pip will look for that package on PyPI and if found, it will download and install the package on your local system.

Download and Install pip:
pip can be downloaded and installed using command-line by going through the following steps:

Step 1 - Download the get-pip.py file and store it in the same directory as python is installed.
Step 2 - Change the current path of the directory in the command line to the path of the directory where the above file exists.
Step 3 - Run the command given below:

```
python get-pip.py
```

and wait through the installation process

And, that's it pip is now installed on your system.

The verify the installation process
Just go to the command line and execute the following command:

```
pip -V
```

Comment: But i couldnt understand the first step thats why ı typed this discussion